# Clickstream performance Scoring formula using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, clickhouse

imagine we have a clickstream and we want to have some everyday score that follows next rules:

1. increase by 1 each impression
2. increase by 10 each click
3. decrease by 1 every second day without impressions (assume there cannot be click without impression)
4. score cannot go bellow zero

First day score is 0 and every next day using the rules from above we're changing it. Every next day the score is based on prior day.

*(each user should have own score)*

The main question how to build such scoring method using SQL.

Thank you.

| user_id | date | impressions | clicks | score | why? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2021-12-13 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 imp, so +1 to our score (initially it's 0) |
| 124 | 2021-12-14 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1st day without imp, so leave as is |
| 124 | 2021-12-15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2nd day, so decrease by 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-16 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3rd day |
| 124 | 2021-12-17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4th day - we cannot go bellow 0 so cannot decrease by 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 124 | 2021-12-19 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 124 | 2021-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 124 | 2021-12-21 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 124 | 2021-12-22 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 124 | 2021-12-23 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 impr, so +1 to our score |
| 124 | 2021-12-24 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1st day without imp, so leave as is |
| 124 | 2021-12-25 | 1 | 0 | 2 | +1 more imp |
| 124 | 2021-12-26 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1st day without imp, so leave as is |
| 124 | 2021-12-27 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2nd day without imp, so decrease by 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-28 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 10(clicks weight) + 1(imp weight) + 1(from prior day) |

UPD1:

```
WITH subset as (
        select 124 as user_id, '2021-12-13' as date, 1 as impressions, 0 clicks
        union all select 124, '2021-12-14', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-15', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-16', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-17', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-18', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-19', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-20', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-21', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-22', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-23', 1, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-24', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-25', 1, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-26', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-27', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-28', 1, 1
        union all select 124, '2021-12-29', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-30', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2021-12-31', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-01', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-02', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-03', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-04', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-05', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-06', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-07', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-08', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-09', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-10', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-11', 0, 0
        union all select 124, '2022-01-12', 0, 0
),

impression_window_tbl AS
 (SELECT *,
         sum(impressions) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
             ORDER BY date) AS impressions_window
  FROM subset),

no_impressions_window AS
 (SELECT user_id,
         date,
         10                                                  AS click_cost,
         1                                                   AS impression_cost,
         2                                                   AS degradation_duration, -- every 2 days
         1                                                   AS degradation_cost,
         impressions_window,
         sum(impressions = 0) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id,
             impressions_window ORDER BY date)               AS row_num_with_no_impressions,
         clicks * click_cost + impressions * impression_cost AS daily_score,          -- ideally only 1 click and 1 impression per day per user
         clicks,
         impressions
  FROM impression_window_tbl),
degradation AS
 (SELECT *,                                                                                            -- this is only specific day degradation value.
         if((modulo(row_num_with_no_impressions, degradation_duration) = 0) = 1
                AND row_num_with_no_impressions > 0, -degradation_cost,
            0)                                                                   AS degradation_value, -- but we have to take into account the degradation_value
         -- but also there is possible cases where no impressions
         sum(daily_score) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
             ORDER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED preceding AND CURRENT ROW) AS inc_cumsum         -- cumulative sum of daily_score

  FROM no_impressions_window)
SELECT *
FROM degradation;
```

Above is a code sample I'm using to play around.

It returns next:

| user_id | date | click_cost | impression_cost | degradation_duration | degradation_cost | impressions_window | row_num_with_no_impressions | daily_score | clicks | impressions | degradation_value | inc_cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2021-12-13 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-14 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-15 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-16 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-17 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-18 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-19 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-20 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-21 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-22 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 2021-12-23 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 124 | 2021-12-24 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 124 | 2021-12-25 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 124 | 2021-12-26 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 124 | 2021-12-27 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 3 |
| 124 | 2021-12-28 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 11 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2021-12-29 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2021-12-30 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2021-12-31 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-01 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-02 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-03 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-04 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-05 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-06 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-07 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-08 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-09 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-10 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-11 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 14 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 14 |
| 124 | 2022-01-12 | 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 |

Degradation value as well as daily_score is for specific day only, it's not cumulative.

inc_cumsum is just an example, ideally we have to do same for degradation_value and sum them, but! we should take into account not going below zero level on daily basis.

---

UPD2:
Solution from @Mikhail does not cover all cases. For data like this one:

```
WITH subset as (
        select 124 as user_id, toDate('2021-12-13') as date, 1 as impressions, 0 clicks
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-14'),  1, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-15'),  1, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-16'),  1, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-17'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-18'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-19'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-20'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-21'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-22'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-23'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-24'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-25'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-26'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-27'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-28'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-29'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-30'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2021-12-31'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-01'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-02'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-03'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-04'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-05'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-06'),  8, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-07'),  4, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-08'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-09'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-10'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-11'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-12'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-13'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-14'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-15'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-16'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-17'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-18'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-19'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-20'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-21'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-22'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-23'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-24'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-25'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-26'),  8, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-27'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-28'),  0, 0
        union all select 124, toDate('2022-01-29'),  0, 0
),
```

Comment: Thank you for good data sample and logic explanation. Still, you should show your efforts. something reasonable / worthwhile for as starting point for us to help you. P.S. I like the question ... but really don't want to start from scratch

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I've added some SQL I'm playing around with. Hope this helps! Thank you! To me it looks a bit recursive. It's easy to do in a python or whatever but SQL makes me crazy. There were actually more problems before which I skipped and simplified to present here. Rows with 0 imps were no exists, so I prefilled missed ones, user_id is not a single one dimension in original data, but anyway, I hope this example have something valuable.

Comment: Btw, it's pretty easy to do without taking care about negative score.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
with temp as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by user_id, grp order by date) pos,
    if(impressions > 0, impressions + 10 * clicks, 0) + 
    if(impressions = 0, mod(row_number() over(partition by user_id, grp order by date), 2) - 1, 0) as total
  from (
    select *, countif(new_grp) over(partition by user_id order by date) grp
    from (
      select *, 
        ((0 = lag(impressions) over(partition by user_id order by date)) and impressions > 0) or 
        ((0 < lag(impressions) over(partition by user_id order by date)) and impressions = 0)  as new_grp
      from subset
    )
  )
), final as (
  select distinct a.*, ifnull(adjustment, 0) adjustment 
  from temp a
  left join(
    select user_id, grp + 1 as grp, -1 - adjustment as adjustment
    from (
          select user_id, grp, sum(total) adjustment
          from temp
          group by user_id, grp
          having adjustment < 0 
      )
  ) b
  on a.user_id = b.user_id 
  and a.grp = b.grp 
  and a.pos = 1
)
select user_id, date, impressions, clicks, if(score < 0, 0, score) as score
from (
  select *, sum(total + if(pos = 1, adjustment, 0)) over(partition by user_id order by date) score
  from final
)
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]